# How to Yii SQL Like

Tags: php, yii

I wish to do a search function for my yii project. I found out in yii that is a function called **`addSearchCondition()`**, then I tried to do the search function.

```
public function actionSearchApp(){

    $searchapp = $_POST['searchapp'];


    $id = Yii::app()->user->getState('id');
    $models = GamesDevelopersApp::model()->findAll('developer_id='.$id);
    array('models'=>$models);
    foreach($models as $model){ 
        $gametitle = CHtml::encode($model->gametitle);

    }

    $search = new CDbCriteria();
    $search->addSearchCondition($gametitle.'LIKE:'.$searchapp);
    $result = GamesDevelopersApp::model()->findAll($search);
    print_r($result);
}
```

**Error Message: Missing argument 2 for CDbCriteria::addSearchCondition()**

Any Suggestion for doing SQL Like in Yii ? or any good example for doing search function in yii

**UPDATED**

```
public function actionSearchApp(){
        $searchapp = $_POST['searchapp'];

        $id = Yii::app()->user->getState('id');
        $models = GamesDevelopersApp::model()->findAll('developer_id='.$id);

        $search = new CDbCriteria();
        $search->addSearchCondition('gametitle', $searchapp); 
        $result = GamesDevelopersApp::model()->findAll($search); 

        print_r($result);

}
```

**Yes it searched, but now it search all data from gametitle, how to make it "where developer_id='id' "?**

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addSearchCondition-detail Manual, do you read it?

Comment: @u_mulder ya, but not really understand

Comment: `addSearchCondition($gametitle, $searchapp)`

Comment: @Karolis not working

Comment: @TheSmile Well, according to your model it looks like you need a column named `gametitle` in the search condition rather than value of it: `addSearchCondition('gametitle', $searchapp)`

Comment: @Karolis the added code in model is @Samuel Liew suggestion ... In DB yes there is a column named `gametitle`

Comment: This article gives some explanation as to how to use LIKE in Yii: [Yii 1.1: Creating a parameterized LIKE query](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/199/creating-a-parameterized-like-query/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you almost did that. Here is the correct code:

```
 $search = new CDbCriteria();
    $search->addSearchCondition($gametitle, $searchapp); //this add the condition and escapes it properly
    $result = GamesDevelopersApp::model()->findAll($search); //here you pass the criteria
    print_r($result)
```

;

The answer of Samuel Liew is totally wrong and SQL injectable.

Comment: not working ... `CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'GG' in 'where clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT * FROM `games_developers_app` `t` WHERE GG LIKE :ycp0 ` it take my last row `GG` to LIKE

Comment: any other suggestion ? Thanks

Comment: from what you've written I assume that the $gametitle var holds the column name. You have to change it like this: $search->addSearchCondition('gametitle', $searchapp); Where $searchapp is the string you are looking for.

Comment: Hi ,Nikola ... thanks for your suggestion it searched !!! But , the search result is all in gametitle no matter the id is who, however I still have to detect the `gametitle` from the correct id.... so far im using `$id = Yii::app()->user->getState('id');` and `$models = GamesDevelopersApp::model()->findAll('developer_id='.$id);` to detect the user ... now how can i mix it with the `$search` code ? can u help me ? thanks=)

Comment: in sql I think something like this : `select gametitle LIKE searchapp from gamesdevelopesrapp where developer_id='theid'` ... but now is : `select gametitle LIKE searchapp from gamesdevelopesrapp`

Answer (score 0):

I successful tried the code and output I need :

Still have to thanks Nikola suggestion

```
public function actionSearchApp(){

        $searchapp = $_POST['searchapp'];

        $id = Yii::app()->user->getState('id');
        $models = GamesDevelopersApp::model()->findAll('developer_id='.$id);

        $search = new CDbCriteria();
        $search->addSearchCondition('gametitle', $searchapp); 
        $search->addCondition('developer_id='.$id);
        $result = GamesDevelopersApp::model()->findAll($search,array('developer_id'=>$id)); 

        print_r($result);

}
```

**use addCondition() for the `where developer_id='id'`** 
Thanks =)